# Add conditional check constraint on Create Table statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a table for storing employee data.  One constraint I would like to add to the salary attribute is requiring the minimum salary be >= $20000.  Another constraint I would like to have is only let the salary be greater than $125000 if the employee's title contains 'Manager.'

Here is the sample code I've written so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    name char(50),
    employeeId int,
    department char(30),
    title char(75),
    birthday date,
    salary int CHECK (salary >= 20000)
);
```

I'm a bit stuck on how to add the constraint to verify only managers can have higher salaries than 125000.  Any help on this?

Comment: how do you determine if someone is a manager?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'll want to check the 'title' attribute to see if it contains 'manager'

Comment: Is it always `'manager'` or can it also be capitalized differently (`'Manager'`, `'MANAGER'` etc.)? Aside from that, why are titles shown as strings in the employee table? Titles should only be defined once, in a `titles` table, and identified by a unique id; then that id should be shown as `title_id` in the `employee` table.

Comment: As an aside, why are you using `CHAR` as a datatype? Now you have loads of unnecessary spaces cluttering up your data. Change it to `VARCHAR2` instead

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
salary int CHECK (salary >= 20000 
                  and (title like '%Manager%' or salary <= 125000))
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  It does seem like simply logic now that I see it in front of me.  For some reason I spent an embarrassing amount of time on this..

Comment: `==` isn't a valid operator in Oracle's SQL dialect.  You'd want `=` if you want to compare equality or a `like` statement if you want to check whether the string `manager` is somewhere in the `title` string.

Comment: I edited your answer to fix several small things. The OP said "salary should be greater than 125000 only if the title contains `'Manager'`". So I changed `manager` to `Manager` (until the OP clarifies the issue of capitalization), I changed your equality check to a "contains" check (with the `like` operator and `%` wildcards), and I changed the `<` to `<= ` since non-managers are allowed to have salary 125000; they are not allowed **greater than** 125000.